# anonymous namespace in c++ cannot access header

Tags: c++

I have an `enum` in the header:

```
namespace somespace
{
    namespace internal
    {

        class SomeClass
        {
            public:

                typedef enum
                {
                    kNone = 0,
                    kKaka = 1,
                }SomeEnum;
        }
    }
}
```

In the cpp, we sometimes use an anonymous namespace with the helper functions.

```
#include <somespace/internal/SomeClass.h>

using somespace::internal;

namespace
{

    bool helpMe(SomeEnum& foo) //does not recognize the enum in the header
    {

    }
}

void SomeClass::memberMethod
{

}
```

But I cannot access the `SomeEnum` in the `.cpp` file. Why is that? 
How can I get around this without polluting the `internal` namespace for example?

Comment: Your `typedef enum` definition is a C-ism. In C++, you can simply write `enum SomeEnum { kNone = 0, kKaka = 1 };`. Since C++11, `enum class SomeEnum { kNone = 0, kKaka = 1 };` is preferred as well.

Comment: This code also can't see `SomeClass`. Clearly there is relevant stuff that hasn't been shown here.

Comment: Incidentally, the default value for the first enumerator in an enumerated type is 0, and the default value for any other enumerator is one more than the value of the enumerator that precedes it. So the `= 0` and `= 1` in the definition of `SomeEnum` above are redundant. In some cases it's appropriate to define enumerators with specific values; in many cases the values aren't important, and the defaults work just fine.

Comment: @PeteBecker i ll add the include because you pointed out. otherwise it suffices to imagine a regular usage of hpp/cpp files. my problem was with the notion of anonymous namespaces..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SomeEnum` is scoped to the class name it is declared in.  To use it you need `SomeClass::SomeEnum`.  This assumes that `SomeClass` is accessible in the scope you have it.  If not then you need `somespace::internal::SomeClass::SomeEnum`